# Xcode debugger enable on on files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a project which includes multiple `ViewController` files. However, if I set one breakpoint in any `ViewController` other than the initial one, the breakpoints and debug simply don't work.

also , print to console statements only works on that initial `ViewController` even if it is not debugging

Is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it doesn't work because the code not running on it, which means if I have two `viewControllers` `viewController1` & `viewController2` and I have a breakpoint in `viewController2` and a function in `viewController1` to navigate to `viewController2`, If the breakpoint doesn't work in `viewController2` then this means that navigation function isn't executed or the breakpoint is in a function which there is no reason to enter this function at all so we conclude that you need to check the main functions you are using to be able to check if these functions are reachable or not